# Unable to create Production Build with Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I had a perfectly running Application developed suing Angular 6.

I upgraded to Angular 7. The whole application was destroyed. It took 4 days to restore the application. Now, I can build the application in development mode and it works.

I am trying to make the production build. However, I get the following error.

Please help so that I can create the production build.

Regards,
Partha

Command: ng build --prod --aot

Output:

```
The /Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/src/undefined path in file replacements does not exist.
Error: The /Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/src/undefined pathin file replacements does not exist.
    at TapSubscriber.operators_1.tap [as _tapNext] (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/normalize-file-replacements.js:26:19)
    at TapSubscriber._next (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/tap.js:59:27)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:209:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:147:22)
    at Subscriber._next (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:90:26)
    at Subscriber.next (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node/host.js:241:21)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
    at DoOperator.call (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/tap.js:32:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:25:22)
    at /Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToObservable.js:10:20
    at Object.subscribeToResult (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:82:29)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan-v1/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:76:14)
```

Answer (score 2):

The angular.json file was corrupted. Instead of

```
"fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

I had the following:

```
"fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/undefined",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.ts"
                }
              ]
```